# Guice + MyBatis : How do I populate a collection inside a DAO object using MyBatis annotations?

Tags: guice

**DAO**

```
public class RequestDAO {

    private Long requestId;
    private Long ownerId;
    private Timestamp whenCreated;
    private List<RequestAttributesDAO> requestAttributes;

}
```

**RequestMapper**

```
@Select("==Select query with multiple joins==") 
List<RequestDAO> getRequestss(int limit);
```

How do it set List inside RequestDAO ?

Comment: section bolding, code formatting

Comment: Are you using the [MyBatis Guice](http://mybatis.github.io/guice/getting-started.html) package? If so could you create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? 

Also is the RequestDAO (Data Access Object) really a DAO or a DTO (Data Transfer Object)? As in the example above it looks more like the latter.